# 'SMTP' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python-3.x, string, templates

```
html = """<title></title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<!--[if mso]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>....."""

s = Template(html).safe_substitute(code="test")

msg.attach(MIMEText(s, "html"))
s.send_message(msg)
```

EDİT TRACEBACK

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-59-f34ee49d6941> in <module>()
          6 msg['To'] = "@mail.com"
          7 msg['Subject'] = "RANDEVU BULUNDU"
    ----> 8 msg.attach(MIMEText(s, "html"))
          9 s.send_message(msg)

/usr/lib/python3.7/email/mime/text.py in __init__(self, _text, _subtype, _charset, policy)
     32         if _charset is None:
     33             try:
---> 34                 _text.encode('us-ascii')
     35                 _charset = 'us-ascii'
     36             except UnicodeEncodeError:

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

how can i solve it ?
if i make s.encode().
giving 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Where are you getting the definition of `MIMEText` from?